# mvc3 EditForModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to get the EditFor or/and the EditForModel to work in mvc3, but it does not render anything on the page.

I can get LabelFor and TextFor to work, but not the model level stuff. Any help would be great.

My controller event is this:

```
 public override ViewResult Index()
        {
            var mystate = new WelcomeModel();
            return View(mystate);
        }
```

Here is my viewmodel:

```
public class WelcomeModel
    {

        [Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(Addresses))]  //resource file value
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public Email RecoverEmail { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Holds a list of attributes to the display elements
        /// </summary>
        public IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttrbutes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public WelcomeModel()
        {
            RecoverEmail = new Email();
            htmlAttrbutes.Add("class", "largeText");
        }
    }
```

Here is my view itself:

```
@model IdentityManager.Models.WelcomeModel

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset class="nolabel">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
               @Html.EditForModel()
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="FormSubmitDiv" class="buttonBar" runat="server">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: and what is the result? how the rendered page looks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view model has a property called `RecoverEmail` which itself is a complex type `Email`. This is not supported automatically by the default editor templates (they recourse into complex sub-types). Brad Wilson [explains this scenario](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html). Another possibility is to write a custom editor template for the `Email` class (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Email.cshtml`) where you can personalize what you need:

```
@model Email
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Address)
</div>
... some other fields
```

Comment: And then call @html.Parial /.RenderParial? Which would be better? One returns the 'details' in html and one renders as an include?

Comment: @Arnej65, no, don't use Partial, RenderPartial. Use `Html.EditorForModel()`. If you define the custom editor template it will automatically be used.

Comment: Sorry new to mvc2/3. So if I have a .cshtml file named Email, then my Welcome.cshtml will know to use it?

Comment: @ Arnej65, yes if inside your Welcome page you use EditorFor or EditorForModel and you have defined an editor template for this type, otherwise it will use the default template. Also take a look at the following blog post: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/